# Which libraries does webkit utilize?

Tags: webkit, gtk

I'm looking for a list of libraries used by webkitgtk/safari.

I've googled, checked wikipedia and even the webkit.org site, to no avail.

Specifically, by libraries I mean libpng, etc.

I pulled the regular webkit repo via svn:

```
svn checkout https://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk webkit
```

I'm building it for x64 and using ASAN (via the set-webkit-configuration script),
then followed [these](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk) instructions:

```
.../Tools/gtk/install-dependencies
.../Tools/Scripts/update-webkitgtk-libs
.../Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --gtk
```

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors. Do you intend on shipping WebKit yoruself, or using a preinstalled system-global one? What version of the WebKit API, 1 or 2? What version of WebKitGTK+? What version of GTK+? If you are building yourself, what configure/cmake flags?

Comment: no configure/cmake flags specifically used, please see edits above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the list of dependencies:
https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKitGTK/Dependencies